# Pause Bootstrap carousel when playing Youtube video

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I have made a carousel which has images and a Youtube video. 
Even when the video is playing the carousel slides and when returned to the video, the video is still playing.

1. I want the carousel to pause when the video is playing and carry on if arrows clicked or if the video ends.
2. Stop video, if it was playing and the user clicked on carousel arrows.

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">

                        <!-- Indicators -->

                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

                        </ol>

                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div id="cal01"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div id="cal02"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pFaJqKqQa2E" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen id="cal3"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Left and right controls -->

                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>

                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How can I achieve this? I wasn't able to find anything similar to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pausing Bootstrap carousel When a Video playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038699/pausing-bootstrap-carousel-when-a-video-playing)

Comment: @IsmailFarooq That could help in the second part of my question, but what about the first part?

Comment: Here is your first part answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950146/check-if-youtube-video-is-playing-and-run-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2 questions were exactly word-by-word my same issues earlier today~

For Youtube iframe videos to trigger a pause on the sliding of the carousel whenever a video is playing, you need to have an indicator on whether a video is considered "playing". You can achieve this by using the player functionalities of the Youtube iframe API with JavaScript.

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Listen to events that involves these states:

- YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
- YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING

And then control the Bootstrap carousel sliding through `.carousel('pause')` :

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods

To be able to listen to such events, you can add to your JavaScript a function called "onPlayerStateChange" (as described within the Youtube iframe API):

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) // triggered everytime ANY iframe video player among the "players" list is played, paused, ended, etc.
{
    // Check if any iframe video is being played (or is currently buffering to be played)
    // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
    {
        // If any player has been detected to be currently playing or buffering, pause the carousel from sliding
        // .carousel('pause') - Stops the carousel from cycling through items.
        // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
        $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('pause');
    }
    else
    {
        // If there are no currently playing nor buffering videos, resume the sliding of the carousel.
        // This means that once the current video is in a state that is not playing (aside from buffering), either it was:
        //     1. paused intentionally
        //     2. paused as an effect of a slide
        //     3. video has ended
        //     4. wasn't totally played from the start
        //     5. and literally any form where the video timer isn't running ;)
        //     - then the carousel would now resume sliding.
        $('#moviesCarousel').carousel();
    }
```

To stop the video if a slide is triggered (if user clicked on either previous or next arrows):

```
// When a slide occurs, pause the current iframe video that is playing
// player.pauseVideo():Void - Pauses the currently playing video.
// Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls
$('#moviesCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
    // The variable "players" contain each Youtube Player for each iframe video
    // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player
    // event.from - The index of the current video (before the slide occurs)
    //            - It is also the index of the corresponding player for the current video
    // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#events
    players[event.from].pauseVideo();
});
```

For reference, here is the full working HTML (works directly, no modifications needed) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Buttons for manually sliding the carousel -->
    <div class="btn-group col-lg-8" role="group" aria-label="Carousel controls">
        <button id="prevMovie" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Prev</button>
        <button id="nextMovie" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Next</button>
    </div>

    <!-- The carousel containing the Youtube iframe videos -->
    <!-- Remember to add the ?enablejsapi=1 in the Youtube embed link as described in: -->
    <!-- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors -->
    <div id="moviesCarousel" class="carousel slide col-lg-8" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <!-- embed is used for responsive size regardless of device -->
            <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item active">
                <iframe id="katniss" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v98Rh9qzmPs?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
                <iframe id="rancho" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-MlkASchodc?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
                <iframe id="logan" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UgJr0bNmTL8?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            // Slide the carousel upon button click
            // .carousel('prev') - Cycles to the previous item
            // .carousel('next') - Cycles to the next item.
            // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
            $('#prevMovie').on('click', function() {
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('prev');
            });
            $('#nextMovie').on('click', function() {
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('next');
            });

            // When a slide occurs, pause the current iframe video that is playing
            // player.pauseVideo():Void - Pauses the currently playing video.
            // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls
            $('#moviesCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
                // The variable "players" contain each Youtube Player for each iframe video
                // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player
                // event.from - The index of the current video (before the slide occurs)
                //            - It is also the index of the corresponding player for the current video
                // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#events
                players[event.from].pauseVideo();
            });
        });

        // Start of snippet from: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var players = []; // would contain 1 player for each iframe video
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
        {
            var allMovieIframes = document.getElementById("moviesCarousel").getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (currentIFrame of allMovieIframes)
            {
                players.push(new YT.Player(
                    currentIFrame.id, // the target iframe video, here it is  either katniss, rancho, or logan
                    { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } }
                ));
            }
        }
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) // triggered everytime ANY iframe video player among the "players" list is played, paused, ended, etc.
        {
            // Check if any iframe video is being played (or is currently buffering to be played)
            // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
            {
                // If any player has been detected to be currently playing or buffering, pause the carousel from sliding
                // .carousel('pause') - Stops the carousel from cycling through items.
                // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('pause');
            }
            else
            {
                // If there are no currently playing nor buffering videos, resume the sliding of the carousel.
                // This means that once the current video is in a state that is not playing (aside from buffering), either it was:
                //     1. paused intentionally
                //     2. paused as an effect of a slide
                //     3. video has ended
                //     4. wasn't totally played from the start
                //     5. and literally any form where the video timer isn't running ;)
                //     - then the carousel would now resume sliding.
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel();
            }
        }
        // End of snippet from Youtube iframe API
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```